# Testing visibility of React component with Tailwind CSS transforms using jest-dom

Tags: testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, tailwind-css, jest-dom

How can I test whether or not a React component is visible in the DOM when that component is hidden using a CSS transition with `transform: scale(0)`?

`jest-dom` has a `.toBeVisible()` matcher, but this doesn't work because `transform: scale(0)` is **not** one of the supported visible/hidden triggers.  Per [the docs](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible):

> An element is visible if all the following conditions are met:
>
> - it is present in the document
> - it does not have its css property `display` set to `none`
> - it does not have its css property `visibility` set to either `hidden` or `collapse`
> - it does not have its css property `opacity` set to 0
> - its parent element is also visible (and so on up to the top of the DOM tree)
> - it does not have the `hidden` attribute
> - if `<details />` it has the `open` attribute

I am not using the `hidden` attribute because it interfered with my transition animations.  I *am* using `aria-hidden`, but that is also not one of the supported triggers.

The simplified version of my component is basically this.  I am using Tailwind CSS for the transform and the transition.

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";

const MyComponent = ({isSelected = true, text}) => (
  <div
    className={clsx(
      isSelected ? "transform scale-1" : "transform scale-0",
      "transition-all duration-500"
    )}
    aria-hidden={!isSelected}
  >
     <span>{text}</span>
  </div>
)
```

I could potentially check for hidden elements with:

- `toHaveClass("scale-0")`
- `toHaveAttribute("aria-hidden", true)`

But unlike `toBeVisible`, which evaluates the entire parent tree, these matchers only look at the element itself.

If I use `getByText` from `react-testing-library` then I am accessing the `<span>` inside the `<div>` rather than the `<div>` which I want to be examining. So this doesn't work:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";

it("is visible when isSelected={true}", () => {
  const {getByText} = render(
    <MyComponent
      isSelected={true}
      text="Hello World"
    />
  );
  expect(getByText("Hello World")).toHaveClass("scale-1");
});
```

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: I ended up using `getByTestId` and `toHaveClass` but this feels really hacky and I'd love to know if there's a better solution.  Like a way to extend `toBeVisible`?  I did `expect(getByTestId("prefix-Hello World")).toHaveClass("scale-1");`

Comment: I believe the issue you're experiencing here is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813527/cannot-check-expectelm-not-tobevisible-for-semantic-ui-react-component). My understanding is the problem isn't so much that the effective visibility calculation is wrong, but that tailwind's CSS isn't being included in the jsdom document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot check expect(elm).not.toBeVisible() for semantic-ui react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813527/cannot-check-expectelm-not-tobevisible-for-semantic-ui-react-component)

Comment: @Liam that's definitely related, but even if all styles are loaded and interpreted properly there is still a problem because `transform: scale(0)` is not considered to be "hidden" (unlike the `display: none` in that question).